# How to add "active" class to styled components in React

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm learning React and i just founded about styled-components and i would like to refactor my code into styled components.

Maybe i didn't understand it at all but i'm trying to make add/remove class on "toggle"

For example:

button--active

Here is what i've tried so far:

```
render() {
    const {active, toggleHamburgerActive } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
          <HamburgerButtonContainer active={active} onClick={toggleHamburgerActive}/>
     </div>
```

styles:

```
const buttonStyles = css`
      border: 1px solid red;
    `;
    
    const getButtonStyles = active => {
      if (active) {
        return hamburgerActiveStyles;
      }
      return buttonStyles;
    };
    
    const hamburgerActiveStyles = css`
      border: 10px solid green;
    `;
    
    export const HamburgerButtonContainer = styled.button`
      ${getButtonStyles}
    `;
```

@EDIT
To make it more clear. active is changing on click but styles are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just forgot to destructure your props:

```
const getButtonStyles = /* this here ---> */({active}) => {
      if (active) {
        return hamburgerActiveStyles;
      }
      return buttonStyles;
    };

const getButtonStyles = /* props is passed here, not only active ---> */props =>
```

You can access props [by passing a callback in an expression](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) as you did.

```
styled.button`
  ${props => ...} // you passed the callback here, so props is passed to it, not only active
`
```

Or if you prefer

```
styled.button`
  ${props => getButtonStyles(props.active)}
`
```

Comment: You are right. I forgot to destructure props.  ({active}) worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called your function using `active` as a param. And You should organise your code like below to pass the active as a prop.

```
const HamburgerButtonContainer = ({ onClick, active }) => {
  const buttonStyles = `
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

  const getButtonStyles = (active) => {
    if (active) {
      return hamburgerActiveStyles;
    }
    return buttonStyles;
  };

  const hamburgerActiveStyles = `
  border: 10px solid green;
`;

  const StyledHamburgerButtonContainer = styled.button`
    ${getButtonStyles(active)}
  `;

  return <StyledHamburgerButtonContainer onClick={onClick} />;
};
```

Comment: I cannot do that because 'active' is not declared

Comment: Actually, you can access props in an expression in the template literal by passing it a callback, like this: `${props => ...}`. The OP did pass a callback to it `${getButtonStyles}`. It's called with props.

Comment: That wouldn't work if the styled component is outside the component as it's usually the case.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera your answer is good aswell i just needed to desctructure 'active'. Thank you !